# Not getting firebase notification on android app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have followed the firebase documentation cloud messaging for android 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Followed these steps :

1. Created project on firebase
2. downloaded google-services.json and added it in project
3. Added below services in manifest file :
   MyFirebaseInstanceIDService

   ```
   <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
               </intent-filter>
           </service>
   ```

   MyFirebaseMessagingService

   ```
   <service android:name=".Service.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
       </intent-filter>
   ```
4. Added meta data in manifest file :

   ```
   <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
           android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
           <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
           android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
   ```
5. I am getting the registration token through

   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

and also added onRefreshToken()

Still I am not getting the notification from firebase console.

Comment: One more thing, just make sure your device Date and Time is correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removed `tools:node="replace"` from application tag in AndroidManifest.xml file and notification is working fine now. There was no issue of fiebase implementation.

Comment: I am having the same issue but I dont have tools:node="replace" in the application tag in AndroidManifest.xml file . What would be the issue?

Comment: Have you done all the process as per firebase instructions ?

Answer (score 0):

In your MyFirebaseMessagingService,
does the method onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) getting called when you try to send the push?

If so, you need to use the NotificationCompat.Builder to build the notification and then notify the OS to create the notification.

You can read the docs here:
https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html

Comment: 1. How are sending the notifications using the console? directly to the user token?

2. Is your app in the foreground or in the background?

3. Are you sending a notification message or data message? there are differences between them...

Comment: Not able to receive the notification through console as well, checked through device token..
Checked with both foreground and background.
Sending through notification message..